# Couldn't find package ia322stdc++6b32

Tags: linux, apt-get

How can I solve this problem

```
sudo apt-get install ia322stdc++6b32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package ia322stdc++6b32
```

**EDIT**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package lib32stdc++6





sudo apt-cache search stdc
lib64stdc++6 - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (64bit)
lib64stdc++6-4.4-dbg - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libgmp3-dev - Multiprecision arithmetic library developers tools
libstdc++6 - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3
libstdc++6-4.4-dbg - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.4-dev - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.4-doc - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (documentation files)
libstdc++6-4.4-pic - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: LaTeX supplementary packages
lib64stdc++6-4.1-dbg - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
lib64stdc++6-4.3-dbg - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.1-dbg - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.1-dev - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.1-doc - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (documentation files)
libstdc++6-4.1-pic - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
libstdc++6-4.3-dbg - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.3-dev - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.3-doc - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (documentation files)
libstdc++6-4.3-pic - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
x11-xserver-utils - X server utilities
```

Comment: why people vote to close this question ? what is wrong ? can someone explain me so I would not do the same mistake next time

Comment: http://superuser.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/ would be more appropriate site for such question. Check the FAQ for the kind of questions that should be asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-cache search stdc`, depends on what distro you are running.  Current version should be 6.4.*.  Check yourself!

Comment: please see my edit, what should I do to install lib32stdc++6

Comment: `gcc --version` , check it,if you are using 4.6 for example you should need the 6-4.6 , 6-4.5 for gcc 4.5 and so on. If i don't know what you need those library for i think it's difficult to help further

Comment: I have 4.4.3 :(, what do you suggest ? should I install the latest ubuntu ?

Comment: check how to upgrade GCC if you don't want to upgrade your whole system, anyways askubuntu.com is more appropriate